# Multiple data series and multiple data tooltip with HighMaps

Tags: highmaps

I would like to display multiple data for the same state in the tool tip. how should i define the data and format the tool tip accordingly?

In the example the defined data is

```
var data = [['in-tn', 1], ['in-ap', 2]]
```

and the tooltip is

```
Random data
Tamilnadu : 1
```

I would like to define my data as

```
  var data = [['in-tn', Rank1 , Value1 , 'Station ID1', Value2],
              ['in-tn', Rank2 , Value2 , 'Station ID2', Value3],
              ['in-ap', Rank3 , Value3 , 'Station ID3', Value5],
              ['in-ap', Rank4 , Value4 , 'Station ID4', Value6]]
```

and get the tool tip when hoverd on 'in-tn' as

```
TamiNadu
Station 1 , Rank = 1, Value1 = 13, Value 2 = 189.76<br>
Station 10, Rank = 2, Value1 = 23, Value 2 = 156.45<br>
```

[My fiddle with data series but without tooltip](https://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/f2sjvogL/19/)

```
//data for which the Highmaps to be generated with all data in tooltip which matches the state code
var data = [['in-tn', 1 , 13 , 'Station 1', 189.76], 
            ['in-tn', 2 , 23 , 'Station 10', 156.45],
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to define the structure of your data for that the Highcharts would "know" how to parse it, so to do that please use the `series.keys` parameter, just like that:

```
series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    keys: ['hc-key', 'rank', 'value', 'stationId', 'value2'],
    states: {
        hover: {
            color: '#FFC300'
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
    }
}]
```

Then you have to define your own tooltip format. You can achieve it using `tooltip.pointFormat`:
 tooltip: {

```
pointFormat: '<span>{point.stationId}, Rank: <b>{point.rank}</b>, Value 1: <b>{point.value}</b>, Value 2: <b>{point.value2}</b></span>'
    }
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1oudhgq3/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/tooltip.pointFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. If you notice the data there are  2 entries for the id 'in-tn' how to display both the 'in-tn' data in the same tooltip.

Comment: Then you need to prepare your own tooltip formatter function. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/0y8jbtqL/

Comment: the "key" and data formatting accordingly worked for me - however, in your jsfiddle, perhaps you have some error, onhover doesnt help it there. But great work & thanks :)
Regards